# Creating views dynamically with autolayout constraints? in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

- UIStackView(main)

  - UIView(sub)

    - UILabel,UIButton etc.
  - UIview (sub)
  - may be others views

All these are programmatically with constraints. And may be UIView of UILabel or UIButtons are create into loops. One by One.

Please help !!

Comment: Why do you use no `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`? They simplify subview creation and layout as well as having a better memory usage. They are both designed for displaying a dynamic count of subviews.

Comment: b'coz I want to create dynamic. I don't know which UI type become first or last. But every view is in it's super view and may be it's expandable.

Comment: I see no reason for not using a collection or table view even after your explanation.

Comment: My views are not fix or how many it is. It's depend on sever response and UI types also.

Comment: Table and collection views are designed for a dynamic number of subviews, and you can always change the number of displayed cells without reloading the full view. You can have multiple cell types with completely different layouts. If you have too many subviews in your stackview, you will get both serious memory and performance problems, while table and collection views will handle very huge numbers of cells without problems.

Comment: Ok, please tell me can I set viewWithTag: automatically to every views while programmatically when I got response from server.

Comment: I think `viewWithTag:` is not the best solution for table or collection views, but you can set the tags in the appropriate data source method. You should better create a suitable data model. Then, updating only visible cells is very easy.

Comment: Have you any demo?

Comment: You will find many examples for table and collection views. Take just a look in Apple's sample code or Ray Wenderlich's blog for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create these views programatically, i would recommend these two libraries. They make adding/removing/updating/managing constraints very easy.

**Objective-c**

https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry

**Swift**

https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit

Answer (score 1):

You can use apple Native [NSLayoutAnchor](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nslayoutanchor#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSLayoutAnchor) to create constraints programatically. Which is sort and simple like SnapKit/Masonry.